# Как проверить в начале весь массив на одно условие, а потом на другое?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть несколько массивов данных. К примеру такого вида:

```
["значение": "asdlkfjhasjd", "значение": "Яблоко", "значение": "adfkljahsdj", "значение": "Банан",]
```

В массиве может быть только Банан, либо только Яблоко, либо Банан и Яблоко, либо вообще ничего. Я перебираю массив через forEach. Мне нужен Банан, но если Банана нет, то мне нужно Яблоко. По сути мне бы подошло условие:

```
if (значение == Банан) {...} else if (значение == Яблоко) {...}
```

, но проблема в том, что Банан может быть в конце массива, а скрипт проверяет значение и видит, что Яблоко подходит и возвращает мне Яблоко. А в приоритете всегда у меня Банан. Как бы сделать так, чтобы в случае, если в массиве есть Банан, то он бы и возвращался? Но если банана нет, то искалось бы Яблоко.

И пока я писала этот вопрос, меня начал смущать момент того, что массив будет перебираться 2 раза. А он довольно большой... Как бы ещё в один перебор уместиться?

Comment: В первом примере у вас, наверное, опечатка? Должны быть фигурные скобки объекта `{}`, а не квадратные скобки массива `[]`? У вас перебирается массив объектов? Или вы имели в виду массив типа `["asdlkfjhasjd", "Яблоко", "adfkljahsdj", "Банан",]`?

Comment: Дак завести флажок на яблоко. Идешь идешь проверяешь если яблоко то фражок в true, встретил банан, вернул банан, сделал break. Дошел до конца без банана, посмотрел было ли яблоко ну и вернул соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `forEach()` можно использовать `for...of` цикл — его можно оборвать, как только найдётся банан, тогда как `forEach()` будет перебирать весь массив, даже если банан найдётся сразу. (Если вам необходимо использовать метод массива, вместо `forEach()` можно использовать `some()` или `find()` — такой перебор можно оборвать, вернув `true`; хотя код станет менее очевидным и читабельным).

```js
const array = ['asdlkfjhasjd', 'Яблоко', 'adfkljahsdj', 'Банан'];

let result = null;

for (const item of array) {
  if (item === 'Банан') {
    result = item;
    break;
  } else if (item === 'Яблоко') {
    result = item;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```